# Find Distance bewteen two Longitude Lattitude-Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, geolocation

I have an requirement where i want to find the difference between two points.Using longitude and lattitude.Each 2 minutes i'm getting packets from a device and inserting into a databse. So i want to find the distance between two consecutive packets for a device. Table contains following columns

```
 1.id
 2.device_d
 3.longitude
 4.lattitude
```

i know using query it is possible to find the distance between two geolocation using query.

```
    SELECT
id, (
  3959 * acos (
    cos ( radians(78.3232) )
   * cos( radians( lat ) )
  * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(65.3234) )
  + sin ( radians(65.3234) )
  * sin( radians( lat ) )
)
) AS distance
FROM markers
```

How cann i make use of above formula for finding **distance between two consecutive rows of a partciular device(using device id)** How can i do this using a **mysql query**.Can anyone help?

Comment: Are these points on our planet?

Comment: Use your current select twice, generating a sequence number and join the 2 so that one row is joined with the following row.

Answer (score 0):

OK, more food for thought...

```
SELECT * FROM bin;
+-----+
| i   |
+-----+
|   1 |
|   2 |
|   4 |
|   8 |
|  16 |
|  32 |
|  64 |
| 128 |
+-----+

SELECT x.i
     , MIN(y.i) next 
  FROM bin x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN bin y 
    ON y.i > x.i 
 GROUP 
    BY x.i;

+-----+------+
| i   | next |
+-----+------+
|   1 |    2 |
|   2 |    4 |
|   4 |    8 |
|   8 |   16 |
|  16 |   32 |
|  32 |   64 |
|  64 |  128 |
| 128 | NULL |
+-----+------+
```

Comment: my doubt is how to get values of two consecutive rows of one vehicle.if i get that i can continue

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id,
 ACOS(SIN( lat_1 * PI) * SIN(lat_2 * PI) + COS( lat_1 * PI) * COS(lat_2 * PI) * COS(( lon_1 - lon_2 ) * PI)) / PI * 60 * 1.1515 AS distance
FROM markers
```

It will give result in miles.

Comment: my doubt is how to get values of two consecutive rows of one vehicle

Comment: You have to make stored procedure in which you have to pass one by one lat and long.
This can't be done in single query.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this. Generate 2 lists of the positions in order with a sequence number added, and join based on the vehicle id and the sequence numbers being consecutive. Then do the calculation.

```
SELECT Sub1.id, Sub1.vehicle_id, ACOS(SIN( Sub1.lat * PI) * SIN(Sub2.lat * PI) + COS( Sub1.lat * PI) * COS(Sub2.lat * PI) * COS(( Sub1.lon - Sub2.lon ) * PI)) / PI * 60 * 1.1515 AS distance
FROM
(
    SELECT id, vehicle_id, longitude, lattitude, @seq:=IF(@prev_vehicle_id=vehicle_id, 1, @seq) + 1 AS seq, @prev_vehicle_id := vehicle_id
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT id, vehicle_id, longitude, lattitude
        FROM markers
        ORDER BY vehicle_id, id
    ) Sub3
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @seq:=1, @prev_vehicle_id:=0
) Sub1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id, vehicle_id, longitude, lattitude, @seq1:=IF(@prev_vehicle_id1=vehicle_id, 0, @seq1) + 1 AS seq, @prev_vehicle_id1 := vehicle_id
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT id, vehicle_id, longitude, lattitude
        FROM markers
        ORDER BY vehicle_id, id
    ) Sub4
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @seq1:=0, @prev_vehicle_id1:=0
) Sub2
ON Sub1.vehicle_id = Sub2.vehicle_id
AND Sub1.seq = Sub2.seq
```

Comment: ok..i will test it...i have a doubt on Sub1.seq = Sub2.seq also distance is in kms??

Comment: The 2 subselects have different starting sequences, hence in one the first item is 1 and the other is is 2. Hence when the sequence numbers match you have one record and the record after it. The distance calculation I just nabbed from the response by @SamarHaider above, but that is easy to change to which ever calculation you want once you have the 2 positions.